# New to C++ and scanf is not properly reading/printing input

Tags: c++, printf, scanf

I'm trying to refresh my memory in writing code using C++ and can't figure out why the follow isn't working:

I'm supposed to read in from scanf the following values:

`3 444 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493`

And then print them each to their own line.  Like so:

```
3
444
12345678912345
a
334.23
14049.30493
```

The code I'm using is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Complete the code.
    int inum;
    long lnum;
    long long llnum;
    char ch;
    float fnum;
    double dfnum;

    scanf("%d%ld%lld%c%f%lf", &inum, &lnum, &llnum, &ch, &fnum, &dfnum);
    printf("%d\n%ld\n%lld\n%c\n%f\n%lf", inum, lnum, llnum, ch, fnum, dfnum);
    return 0;
}
```

But the output produced by this is:

```
3
444
12345678912345

0.000000
0.000000
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any reason you need to use `scanf`?  Please search the internet for "scanf not safe".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's from hackerrank.com... just running through some tests to get back in a rhythm.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I guess I can also use `cin`...

Comment: Is the *requirement* to use `scanf` or to read data from the standard input?  You could use `cin >> inum;` for example.

Comment: It's not a requirement, but it says to use `scanf` reading over a million values from stdin because it's faster.  So I figured I'd just use it by default.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews can you tell me why it's not working?  I don't understand

Comment: @hax0r_n_code: the code you showed is C, not C++.  C uses things like `scanf()` and `printf()`, C++ uses things like `std::cin >>` and `std::cout <<`.

Comment: Use a debugger and find out the value read in for `ch`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, the code is C++ because `iostream` and `cstdio` is used.

Comment: @MikeCAT: So, the code is actually using the C++ `std::scanf()` and `std::printf()` wrappers, not the C `scanf()` and `printf()` functions. This is how `using namespace std` can confuse people and get them into trouble.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If the code is being compiled by a `C++` compiler then it's `C++`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The language of the functions that the program calls is irrelevant, they could have been written in `Pascal` or `Fortran`, doesn't make it a `Pascal` program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including spaces in your `scanf()` format string to help `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", &inum, &lnum, &llnum, &ch, &fnum, &dfnum);
```

`scanf()` returns the number of value it actually read, eg:

```
if (scanf("%d %ld %lld %c %f %lf", &inum, &lnum, &llnum, &ch, &fnum, &dfnum) == 6)
    printf("%d\n%ld\n%lld\n%c\n%f\n%lf", inum, lnum, llnum, ch, fnum, dfnum);
```

That being said, you tagged your question as C++, but the code you showed is mostly C and not using any C++ functionality (your `using` statement doesn't count since you are not actually using anything from the `std` namespace).  What you are attempting would look more like this in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int inum;
    long lnum;
    long long llnum;
    char ch;
    float fnum;
    double dfnum;

    if (cin >> inum >> lnum >> llnum >> ch >> fnum >> dfnum)
        cout << inum << "\n" << lnum << "\n" << llnum << "\n" << ch << "\n" << fnum << "\n" << dfnum;

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;

    int inum;
    long lnum;
    long long llnum;
    char ch;
    float fnum;
    double dfnum;

    if (getline(cin, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        if (iss >> inum >> lnum >> llnum >> ch >> fnum >> dfnum)
            cout << inum << "\n" << lnum << "\n" << llnum << "\n" << ch << "\n" << fnum << "\n" << dfnum;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The exercise seemed to focus on format specifiers, are they unnecessary when using `cout`?

Comment: @hax0r_n_code: yes, because there is no format string involved.  The `>>` and `<<` operators are overloaded for individual data types so they implicitly know WHAT they are reading/writing and HOW to read/write them.

Comment: This code only passed one of four test cases..  If you are curious and feel like giving it a try let me know what the solution is.  I'm very curious.  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-basic-data-types?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: @hax0r_n_code: There are no additional test cases at that link, only an explanation of how to read values in general.  If you are having specific problems, please edit your question with details.

Comment: Both `scanf` and `printf` are guaranteed to be in the `std` namespace because the header `<cstdio>` was included (it can optionally put them in the global namespace but not required).

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't use `using namespace std`.
2. Check the return value of `scanf`.
3. Read the `fscanf` man page, especially for the `%c` modifier.
4. Read the `fprintf` man page, since its modifiers are different from the `fscanf` modifiers.